# Firebase Crashlytics with chromium (android)

Tags: android, c++, chromium, crashlytics, ninja

Is there possible add Crashlytics to the chromium android? This is easy with projects based on gradle with Android Studio https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0&platform=android#java  . But the chromium build uses ninja build tool - without gradle and Android Studio. So I do not understand how to add Crashlytics to the chromium.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that one can build NDK projects with Gradle and Ninja, so this claim might be a misconception of what Gradle is able to do and what it isn't able to. Likely you'll have to add [`crashlytics.h`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/master/firebase-crashlytics-ndk/src/main/jni/libcrashlytics/include/crashlytics/external/crashlytics.h) and `libcrashlytics.so` for native crash reporting.

There's also an external [`mini-chromium`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/mini_chromium) module contained.

> [Crashpad](https://chromium.googlesource.com/crashpad/crashpad/+/master/README.md) is the chief consumer of `mini_chromium`.